# HubSpot macro not outputting markup

Tags: html, jinja2, hubspot, hubspot-cms

I have a `my_macro.html` defined which currently looks like this:

```html
<!--
  templateType: "none"
  isAvailableForNewContent: false
-->


{% macro video_card(background_image, video_link) %}

    <div class="videoCard" style="background-image: url({{ background_image }});">
      <a class="button--play" id="play-video"></a>
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>

{% endmacro %}
```

In HubSpot, within my `custom module`, I'm trying to use this macro. I have the following:

```html
{% import '/website/assets/hubl/my_macros.html' as macros %}

<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero__video">
    {{ macros.video_card }} <!-- this is where I'm trying to print markup -->
  </div>
</div>
```

However, on the output, where I should expect the markup, I see the following message:

`com.hubspot.jinjava.lib.fn.MacroFunction@9d25d51`

Unsure why? I've followed the documented `import` and `my_macro.html` file name structure [defined here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/hubl/variables-macros-syntax#import).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, the correct way to use macros in a custom module would be:

`{% from '/website/assets/hubl/my_macros.html' import videoCard %}`

And its usage would be:

`{{ video_card('image.jpg') }}`

Answer (score 0):

your macro has 2 parameters `video_card(background_image, video_link)`, but in your template

```
{{ macros.video_card }} <!-- this is where I'm trying to print markup -->
```

you forgot to pass any parameters ?

it sould be like:

```
{{ macros.video_card('bg-image.png', 'video.mp4') }}
```

Comment: Hi cizario, I've tried the macro without the two parameters too so it's: `{% macro video_card%}<h1>test</h1>{% endmacro %}`. And even with no parameters involved, I get the message